# linq to xml or xsd approach

Tags: c#, xsd, linq-to-xml

There appears to be a fair amount of questions about linq to xml, and also about xsd.  I want to know as a new C# developer, I need to utilize xml to provide settings for a feature that I am working on.

It seems that writing an XSD document and using xsd.exe to generate the C# code is a good way to go, because there's no need to hand write the settings class, saving time, eliminating code, etc.  However how should I compare this method with using Linq to XML? I am asking it seems that I'd have to write more code to query the xml and that's not such a good idea to me.  What exactly is the benefit of using Linq to XML and in which situations can it be applied?

I get the feeling that Linq to XML is just another fancy way to work with XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Linq-to-XML is just another way to work with XML. It is somewhat simpler and more concise than the old `System.Xml` namespace.

If you're using XML to store settings, why not use the `System.Configuration` namespace? This is by far the simplest way to include settings in a .NET application. The `ConfigurationManager` class allows simply retrieval of configuration settings via a key/value pattern from an app.config / web.config file.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: thanks for the idea, however I was making up what I thought might be a real world use case, but I won't forget it.

Comment: When you have XML that you need to parse & work with, Linq-to-XML can make it easier. It is 'just another way', but it's nice & easy.